# How can i use recursion properly on javascript for making license plates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I want to know all the combinations for Costa Rica alphanumeric license plates, the format of these license plates are 3 consonants a dash and another 3 numbers (xxx-xxx)

I have already made some outputs of license plates, but I don't know if what I have done is okay

```
var letra = "";
var numLetra = 0;
var letras = ["B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
var tempPlaca = [];
var placas = [];
var placa = "";
function getRndInteger() {
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
}
function getRndLetra() {
    numLetra = Math.floor(Math.random() * (21 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
}
generatePlaca();

function generatePlaca() {
    // Genera las letras
    for (var u = 0; u < 3; u++) {
        getRndLetra();
        letra = letras[numLetra];
        tempPlaca.push(letra);
        letra = "";
    }
    tempPlaca.push("-");
    // Genera los numeros
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        getRndInteger();
        tempPlaca.push(num);
    }
    placa = tempPlaca.join("");
    if (findInArray(placas, placa) == false) {
        placas.push(placa);
        tempPlaca = [];
        placa = "";
        generatePlaca();
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(placas));
function findInArray(ar, val) {
    for (var i = 0, len = ar.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (ar[i] === val) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My output:

```
["GCT-381","BYG-097","KMV-305","PRZ-046","HFC-147","LQC-268","MZL-631","NVH-843"....
```

And I don't know why in some cases the license plate is not in the right format like this:

```
"PB-557","JT-536"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your letter random index is incorrect. It should only be from 0-20, since your array size is 21;

Change your `getRndLetra` function to this:

```
function getRndLetra() {
    numLetra = Math.floor(Math.random() * letras.length);
}
```

Problem: when random returns 21, you get `letras[21]` which is `undefined` thats why it sometimes appears that it's missing 1 letter.

Answer (score 2):

You could take the length of the array/string and multiply with it.

I changed the array to a string which works fo a single letter.

```js
var letra = "";
var numLetra = 0;
var letras = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
var tempPlaca = [];
var placas = [];
var placa = "";
function getRndInteger() {
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}
function getRndLetra() {
    numLetra = Math.floor(Math.random() * letras.length);
}
generatePlaca();

function generatePlaca() {
    // Genera las letras
    for (var u = 0; u < 3; u++) {
        getRndLetra();
        letra = letras[numLetra];
        tempPlaca.push(letra);
        letra = "";
    }
    tempPlaca.push("-");
    // Genera los numeros
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        getRndInteger();
        tempPlaca.push(num);
    }
    placa = tempPlaca.join("");
    if (findInArray(placas, placa) == false) {
        placas.push(placa);
        tempPlaca = [];
        placa = "";
        generatePlaca();
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(placas));
function findInArray(ar, val) {
    for (var i = 0, len = ar.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (ar[i] === val) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```